# Вывести данные из разных таблиц django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-model, views

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно вывести данные из разных таблиц, имеющих связь друг с другом, в persons_list. Необходимо заменить id значениями LoanTypeParticipation и Name.
Сейчас получаю следующий результат:

```
0: {Id_Incidents: 120, Id_Group: 13, Type_Participation: "p", Id_People: 2, Competencies: "есть"}
```

Views.py

```
def load_table(request):
    error = ''
    id_incidents = request.session.get('Id_Incidents', 'ничего не передано')

    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.user:
            try:
                persons = AkpGroup.objects.filter(Id_Incidents=120)  # запрос в базу данных

            except AkpGroup.objects.DoesNotExist:
                persons = None

            pers = persons.all().values('Id_Incidents', 'Id_Group', 'Type_Participation', 'Id_People', 'Competencies')
            persons_list = list(pers)
            return JsonResponse(persons_list, safe=False)
```

Models.py

```
class AkpPeople(models.Model):
    Id_People = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Идентификатор участника группы АКП')
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Ф.И.О.')
    Post = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Должность:')

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        # return self.Name
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.Name, self.Post)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'akp_people'
        verbose_name = 'Участник группы АКП'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Участники групп АКП'


    class AkpGroup(models.Model):
        Id_Group = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Идентификатор участника группы АКП')
        Id_Incidents = models.ForeignKey('AkpIncidents', models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Идентификатор инцидента')
        Id_People = models.ForeignKey('AkpPeople', models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Ф.И.О. участника')
        Competencies = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Компетенции')
    
        LoanTypeParticipation = (
            ('d', 'Руководитель группы'),
            ('p', 'Член группы')
        )
        Type_Participation = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LoanTypeParticipation,
                                              verbose_name='Тип участия')
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можете добавить в модели функцию для получения той информации, которая нужна по запросу. Пример

```py
class AkpGroup(models.Model):
   ...

# функция для получения полей
  def needs_data(self, pk):
    people = AkpPeople.objects.get(pk=pk)
    name = people.Name
    return{"LoanTypeParticipation":self.LoanTypeParticipation, "name":name}
```

Как пример реализовал возвращение только двух полей. Во `views.py` можете вызвать

```
def load_table(request):
.....
  data = {}
  for person in persons:
    data{person.Id_People} = person.needs_data(person.Id_People])
  return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Вообще, я сторонник выносить всю логику для базы данных в функции классов для `models.py`. Даже для самых простейших манипуляций

Comment: Прошу прошение: при использовании данного решения получается ошибка: `Field 'Id_People' expected a number but got <AkpPeople: AkpPeople object (2)`. Что необходимо дополнительно подправить (получается, что я пытаюсь положить весь объект в поле данных)? 

Наткнулся дополнительно на альтернативное решение с помощью сериализации данных моделей, в каких случаях объективно его использовать?

Comment: @Denis исправил, ошибся. Конечно, если вы пишете RestAPI, то прогнать данные через сериализацию - милое дело и отдавать JSON самое то, что надо. View будет разгружен по максимуму

Comment: я использовал этот код, но у меня получается ошибка: _'AkpGroup' object is not subscriptable_. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано?

`data = []
 for person in persons:
 data[person["Id_People"]] = person.needs_data(person["Id_People"])
 return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)`

Comment: @Denis исправил, там Quryset должен быть и к нему через точку можно обращаться для получения полей